# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'typeof Foods'

Tags: php, angularjs, angular

Looking at my code below, i am trying to delete clients from the my datatable using the checkboxes. When i tick a checkbox, i see in the console that the object's properties have been fetched from the databasae. i am trying to delete by id but the terminal raises this error "Property  'id' does not exist on type 'typeof Clients'". I haven't found any solution yet after my search. Any help?

//Http service

```
@Injectable()

 export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {

  }



  deleteFood(food) {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/food/${id}')
      .map((response:Response) => response.json())
  }
}
```

//table

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let food of Foods; let i = index">
      <td><input #{{food.id}} [(ngModel)]="food.selected" type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(food)"></td>

      <td>{{client.type}}</td>
      <td>{{client.location}}</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" (click)="deleteFood()">Delete</button>
```

//component

```
  export class FoodComponent {

  Foods : Foods[] = []; 



  constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private router: Router){



   selectedFood = Foods;

   deleteFood(){
    this.httpService.deleteFood(this.selectedFood.id)
     .subscribe(data =>{
       console.log(data)
     })
  }

  checkbox(food){
    food.selected = (food.selected) ? false: true;
    this.selectedFood = food;
    console.log(this.selectedFood);
  }
}
```

//Food.ts

```
  export class Food{

  constructor(
    public type:string,
    public location: string,

 ){}
}
```

Comment: could you please post your `Client` file and remove laravel backend please ? (the one referenced in `import {Clients} from './Client';`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component you are assigning the `Clients` type to your `activeClient` property instead of defining its type. And your Clients class has no static property `id`, that's why the compiler complains when you access `this.activeClient.id`.

If you change:

```
activeClient = Clients;
```

to:

```
activeClient: Clients;
```

You should not have the problem anymore.